# TCP client server : blocking connect call

Tags: tcp, blocking, connect

I am building a distributed application that needs TCP for communication. The final experiments will involve thousands of servers with about 10-100 fold as many clients communicating with them. The current design is to make connection, communicate and then close the connection, for every transaction.

1. Since I had only done some simple multi threaded servers with a few clients, I chose blocking sockets for the communication(they sounded easy). I am not sure if this approach will scale high enough. Can some one share their experience?
2. Currently, the code is running on a single machine(48 cores/local loopback) with three servers processes and a few clients. Clients have a tight for loop where they make a connection, communicate with any one server and then break the connection. These initial tests require the clients to make somewhere like a million iterations of the for loop. Basically, it is rigorous testing as we scale the experiments up.
   Randomly, some of the clients get stuck while they try to connect to the server.At the sane time, this server may be communicating fine with other clients. All calls are blocking.
   Can some one suggest what's happening? The listen queue of the server(multi threaded) is 50 and one client does about 1500 connections a second. ( Its a distributed system for high end work loads :))
   Can a prior unbroken connection between this client-server be a reason?

Any sharing of experience would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a good idea to use blocking sockets for the scenario that you mentioned. First things is that you should use non-blocking sockets. And secondly; If you are writing your server on Microsoft Windows then you can consider using I/O Completion Ports for the purpose and in case your sever is implemented on Linux then go for "epoll" will scale good.

The biggest issue here is that by design it seems like you are managing one socket/connection per thread on your server. And you will exhaust your system resources by creating so many threads and its slower to create thread for every connection.

Comment: Thanks Tayyab...we decided to use some sort of hash table/map to cache the connections. So, now the clients will store the sockets in this hash table and this adds some flexibility that we need not make and break connections every time. It may though limit my server processes because I understand that a process can make at max 1024 live connections in TCP(Linux). And we will not have root permissions to alter this limit on every m/c.